# Question is about keyword searches on the Market

Tags: android

I am the developer of an app called FileLinx.  When I connect to the Android Market, either on an Android device or on a PC, and search on the word "FileLinx", I find my app and other apps called "Send Space", and "Large Document" (two versions). Since FileLinx is a manufactured word, there is no reason for a search on "FileLinx" to bring up these two (potential) competitors.  I have searched the descriptions of these two competing apps, and have not found the word "FileLinx" (in any case combination)  in their information. My questions: 1) is there another way of injecting keywords that I am not aware of?  2) Is the injection of a competitor's app name in a "description field" legitimate within the Android guidelines? 3) is there any way to report this abuse?

Answer (score 0):

Are those apps the same shown in the "related" field on your apps market site?
Probably google simply shows related apps if they don't find more hits to the searched word...

How exactly they find out what apps are related I don't know, but as far as i know they check the description.

I don't think there is an abuse to report. And isn't competition good for the business ;-)
Is your app also shown when you search for there's?

Comment: I agree that this is not "abuse", unless the Android market folks prohibit it (I re-entered the question to make that clearer, inadvertently generating two questions! Sorry.) Apparently, however, at least one other developer considers it abuse, and sent me a nasty letter when I listed their application (Cortado) in my app "description", which I did as a test. When you search on "Send Space" (or sendspace") it originally did not pop up FileLinx, but after I included "Send Space" and "sendspace", it did.